# Resizing images to fit into ViewPager, outOfMemory exception

Tags: android, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, image-scaling

I've setup a viewPager which should show around 50 images with a resolution of 1500,2100px. The images are provided by the user self. So I need to downscale the images which I do with this bit of code:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    //imageFile is a string to the image location.
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagefile);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);
```

When the image is downscaled I add it to the viewpager in a arrayList which works perfectly with only a few images. But now I need to load in 50 images, how am I supposed to do this? I'm getting outOfMemory errors, even after I downscaled the images.

The images are added with this code (to the ViewPager):

```
    @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    //int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
    //imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    //imageView.setImageResource(pages.get(position));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(pages.get(position));
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}
```

I hope to get a good suggestion. I was thinking myself of loading only a few images and adding them dynamicly, but I don't know how I can destroy loaded images once I don't need them anymore.
I'm open to any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Fragments and FragmentPagerAdapter in ViewPager. In this method only 3 fragments(pages) are stored in the ViewPager Stack at any given point of time.

1. Previous Page
2. Current Page
3. Next Page

Ex:- If you are in the 2nd page of the ViewPager the ViewPager stack contains  Page1, Page2 and Page3. If you swipe from Page 2 to Page 3, Page 4 is loaded on to the stack and Page 1 is removed from the stack.

Using this in your app will save a lot of memory as only 3 images will be present in the memory at any given time.

This has been explained well in the developer page
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

An example of this implementation -

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

You will have to integrate this code with your code. Let me know if you need any further help!:)

Comment: This would be a good solution! Going to read all about it now, if I have questions I'll get back here.

Comment: Do you have a example of an adapter which works with this? Can't really solve it.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, click on File > New > Android Application Project>Next>Next>Next>Blank Activity and in Navigation Type choose "scrollable tabs+swipe". This will generate an app with viewpager which uses a fragments adapter. Should make things a lot more easier for you to understand. Let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, but will check it out.

Comment: Checked it out, will try to incorporate my own design in it. Looks promising!

Comment: It worked perfectly! Still making it better, but thanks for suggesting it!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `BitmapFactory.Options` to load scaled down version of image into memory.

You can refer this [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)

Make use of `inSampleSize`, set its value to greater than 1.

Comment: Okay, but what value do I need to choose then? On what does that depends?

Comment: The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels